# Does the YouTube Data API quota cost go down when you limit the max results?

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

I cannot seem to find anything on this.

I am using the YouTube Data's Search API:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list`.

It says that a request made will have a quota cost of **100** units.

However, if you make a request, it will return **5** results.

There is a `maxResults` request parameter which can limit the number of results that are returned.

If I set this to `1`, will the quota cost become **20**?

Comment: The answer is no: with `maxResults` min value `1` or max value `50` or anything in between, the quota cost is the same: 100 units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quota is per **request**. The amount of data returned by that request doesn't matter.

If [Search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) allowed max result of 1000000 rows vs 5 rows Cost to your quota would be the same.

[image]

[Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)